# How to logon programmatically on a Windows machine

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, authentication

It is possible to use the logonuser function for logging onto a domain.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx

I want to logon programatically from C# onto a windows machine which is not part of any domain. How to achieve this?

I am using the following Program to logon :

```
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        internal void validateusercredentials(string username, string password, string hostname)
        {

            assert.isnotnull(username);
            intptr tokenhandle = new intptr(0);
            windowsidentity windowsid = null;
            try
            {
                const int logon32_provider_default = 0;

                const int logon32_logon_network = 3;
                tokenhandle = intptr.zero;
                bool success = logonuser(username, ".", password, logon32_logon_network,
                                            logon32_provider_default, ref tokenhandle);
                console.writeline("the return value of logon user is " + success);



                if (!success)
                {
                    int lastwindowserror = marshal.getlastwin32error();
                    if (lastwindowserror == error_logon_failure)
                    {
                        string message = string.format("invalid credentials supplied for user {0}", username);
                        console.writeline(lastwindowserror);
                        throw new invalidcredentialexception(message);

                    }
                }

            }
            catch (exception e)
            {

                console.writeline(e.message);
                trace.traceerror(e.message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (tokenhandle != intptr.zero)
                {
                    closehandle(tokenhandle);
                }
                if (windowsid != null)
                {
                    windowsid.dispose();
                    windowsid = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you actually want to logon to a domain account, or to a local account?

Comment: I tried logon to a local account

Comment: You'll need to show us the code you tried to use and provide details as to what went wrong.

Comment: LogonUser(username, hostname, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref tokenHandle). This is what I tried. The value of hostname is the complete machine name.

Comment: And what error code is returned?

Comment: I am getting the error code 1326.

Comment: "Unknown user name or bad password."  Double-check the details.  Also, try `L"."` as the domain name rather than the machine name.

Comment: I tried with hostname as ".".Also I tried the logon for a different user. Both the cases are failing.

Comment: Please post a complete program exhibiting the problem (but with a fake password).  My best guess at the moment is that you're not P/Invoking LogonUser correctly.

Comment: I have added the code in the content.

Comment: You haven't included the part where `logonuser` is defined.

Comment: I have edited the description and added the definition for the logon user.

Comment: You're defining LogonUser but calling logonuser.  Aren't function names case sensitive in C#?  Anyway, since you're explicitly specifying the Unicode character set, it might be worth trying LogonUserW instead of just LogonUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the machine is not part of your domain, you cannot use your domain credentials.

If you have a local account, you can instead use the local name of the computer as domain name and your local user and password as user and password.

Comment: LogonUser(username, hostname, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,                                            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref tokenHandle);  I tied this with the correct credentials and domainname as the name of the windows machine.But still it is not logging in.

Comment: Use "." to indicate local authentication. If it still fails add details of GetLastError